# Lower bound of a strongly convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, non-smooth-analysis

Let $f,h\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be two strongly convex functions such that $f\ge h$ and $f\left( x^*\right)=h\left( x^*\right)$, where $x^*$ is a joint unique minimizer for both. Assume that $f$ is non-differntiable and $h$ is continuously differentiable.

Take any $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $f\left( x\right)\ge f\left( y\right)$. Can we say that $f\left( x\right)- f\left( y\right)\ge h\left( x\right)- h\left( y\right)$?

[image]

I encountered this problem while analyzing an optimization algorithm. I tried to use the the multi-variable mean value theorem (although $f$ is non-differentiable in infinitely many points). Any ideas on even if this statement is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is not true. Think about this counterexample for $n=1$: Let's denote by $z_0\approx 4.89$ the bigger one of the two roots of $g(x)=3x^{4/3}-1-x^2 $. Then the counterexample is given by
$$h(x)=x^2$$
and
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x^2,\qquad x<1\\ 3x^{4/3}-1,\ x\in[1,z_0]\\
x^2,\quad x>z_0
\end{cases}
$$
at the points $x=z_0$ and $y=1$. Both functions have the same value at point $x$, but as $h(y)=1$ and $f(y)=2$, so the function $f$ is growing less in this interval.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To my understating of the concept of strong convexity, it seems that the function $f$ is not strongly convex, since it is linear in the segment $1\le x\le 2+\sqrt 2$. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I appreciate that.

Comment: I improved my post, so it should be correct now. Please tell me if there is still anything incorrect.

Comment: Now it seems correct. You "simply" tried to find $h$ with a steeper descent in some interval. Thanks!

Comment: By the figure you added in your solution, it seems that if we will construct $h$ in a way such that in every point its slope (or norm of the gradient) will be smaller than the slope of $f$, then the statement will be true. Is that seem correct to you?

Comment: In $\mathbb R$ this is correct. But I don't think that it is still correct in higher dimensions. The counterexample which comes into my mind is $h(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+|x|$. Then take two points on a equipotential line of $f$. Clearly $f$ is constant, but $h$ canges its values. I haven't checked this into detail whether all conditions are satisfied. Maybe you can do this and help others in the future who got stuck at the same problem.

Comment: I intend to that, since for any strongly convex and non-differentiable function $f$, I want to construct a strongly convex and continuously differentiable function $h$, such that $f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\ge h\left(x\right)-h\left(y\right)$. I'm pretty sure that it is possible to find such $h$, but I'm straggling how to construct it. Hopefully I will establish some results in the coming days.